# How to separate functionality from presentation in React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux

I have a login form that requests a JWT token from an API. I want to separate my network request as I use this in multiple places in my app.

Should I move the request to my Redux reducer? Or do I make a new file for the sole purpose of reusing the network function? What's the best practice here?

[image: Folder structure]

Comment: you can just make a separate folder like `utils` for get and post requests and then in your action file you can call them

Comment: Reducers are just pure functions that take the previous state and an action to return the next state. They don't deal with network requests.

Answer (score 0):

There are many way to structure your project folder. It depends on your project. If you project is small, you could split by redux types like components, reducers, actions, containers, screens.

But if your project is big and you want to sustain easily, I suggest that you should use [ducks approach](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/scaling-your-redux-app-with-ducks-6115955638be). This is a good article about it, I think you should take a look